# Sinon stub of dns lookup doesn't get to a callback for lookup

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I am using dns.lookup method in Nodejs to get the IP address of the domain.

That code looks like this:

```
module.exports = async function collectDns() {
    lookup('google.com', { all: true, family: 4 }, (err, addresses) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(addresses);
    });
};
```

I am writing unit test for it using Mocha and Sinon for stubs. This is how my code for it looks like:

```
beforeEach('stub deps', () => {
        lookupFake = {
            address: '127.0.0.1',
            family: 4,
        };
        revert = collectDns.__set__({
            'lookup': stub().resolves(lookupFake),
        });
});
it('run DNS lookup', async () => {
    const collectDns = rewire('../collectdns');
    collectDns();
});
```

What I am experiencing is that it never gets to a callback after doing the lookup call. Can someone advice, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that there is a `[yields][1]` method in sinon that does exactly what I expect - calls the callback.

So, I adjusted this:

```
revert = collectDns.__set__({
    'lookup': stub().yields(lookupFake),
});
```